# When is nvm useful given that node.js 6 has good backward compatibility with node.js 4?

Tags: node.js, nvm

NVM (Node version manager) is for managing different versions of node.js. However, since node.js v6 has good backward compatibility with node.js 4, wouldn't it make sense to simply upgrade to v6? Stick to one version. Wouldn't that make life easier? What are some situations when nvm would be useful?

Comment: For manually investigating issues with your app that might occur in older Node versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have versions in the future that won't be backward compatible, or some of your old client are still running on Node.js version 0.x.x.